# How to specify what files you want to read from different directories

Tags: shell

I have some files in different directories. Some files are named         profiles-tc_0974950_30190-r-00002.avro and others are named profiles_060415084722_30129-r-00012.avro. When I run my script I want to be able to specify  files that start with profiles-tc and other times when I do not want to read those files.

When I run my script for one of the two cases I have the following:

bash move_files2.sh    profile/generate/work/profiles-tc*

However, when I run this it's only reading one file.

```
FILES=$1

for f in $FILES
do
   echo "$f"
   echo "Processing $f file..."
done
```

Comment: `$1` is the first argument. You are saving the first file that the glob expands to into `$FILES` and then looping over it (in a way that will have problems with files with whitespace in the names). Use `for f; do` to loop over all the arguments (same as `for f in "$@"; do` since `"$@"` is the default).

Comment: @ Etan Reisner. Thank you very much. That works. The only thing I am little confused about is when you have `for f; do` . How does it know what files it's reading? Also, what if you had a second for loop inside the first one which read files from a different directory. If you use the `for f; do`. How does it know which files to read?

Comment: The glob on your command line is expanded *immediately* by the shell. Your script sees the individual files as individual arguments. It doesn't see the glob. So `for f; do` just loops over all the arguments passed to the script. A second loop would do the same thing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the param can fix the problem:

```
bash move_files2.sh "profile/generate/work/profiles-tc*"
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the pattern contains spaces (among other things).